# LeafletJS: How to get zoom delta or animation copletion % while zoom is animating?

Tags: leaflet, zooming

In LeafletJS 1.3.1 I need to redraw some stuff during zoom animation.
I have `zoomstart`, `zoomend`, `zoom`, `zoomanim` events, but none of them fired repeatedly during zoom animation: [Issue 5664](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5664)
So, I have to implement zoom animation based on timer or on `requestAnimationFrame` handler.
Here I got a problem: I can not find, where can I get any type of map's zoom animation progress that corresponds actual map's zoom level during animation.

For example, while animating from zoom level 5 to zoom level 6, I **expect** that `map` has some sort of property where current actual zoom is kept. In each `animtionFrame` callback functuon, I can read this property and get current zoom value each time I call this method: `5.0, 5.1, 5.25, 5.3, 5.4, ..., 6.0`.

Could you help me with getting this value during zoom animation? Or give an idea to sync my operations with map's actual scale level.

Comment: "I expect that `map` has some sort of property where current actual zoom is kept": beware of your expectations, rely on facts / source code. See this post on GIS Stack Exchange: [resize marker at same time as map zoom animation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273514/leaflet-resize-marker-at-same-time-as-map-zoom-animation/273540#273540)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't thought it is made through transitions. Will answer myself later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273514/leaflet-resize-marker-at-same-time-as-map-zoom-animation/273540#273540